# Restrict access to a specific type of entity

Tags: authentication, access-control

I want to create a web service that can only be accessed by a specific type of entity: my own mobile application. Is there any well-accepted methods to do this?

I'm thinking about embedding a secret into this mobile application, but it seems to be susceptible to reverse engineering and can be easily sniffed on network. I would appreciate if anyone can suggest me some alternatives.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client SSL certificate authentication would be something you could consider. Instead of providing credentials, your server will request you to provide a certificate (which you can embed in your application).

A small overview I took from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake):

> The following full example shows a client being authenticated (in
>   addition to the server like above) via TLS using certificates
>   exchanged between both peers.
>
> Negotiation Phase:
>
> - A client sends a ClientHello message specifying the highest TLS    protocol version it supports, a random number, a list of suggested
>     cipher suites and compression methods.
> - The server responds with a ServerHello message, containing the chosen    protocol version, a random number, cipher suite and
>     compression    method from the choices offered by the client. The
>     server may also    send a session id as part of the message to perform
>     a resumed    handshake.
> - The server sends its Certificate message (depending on the selected    cipher suite, this may be omitted by the server).
> - The server requests a certificate from the client, so that the    connection can be mutually authenticated, using a CertificateRequest
>     message.
> - The server sends a ServerHelloDone message, indicating it is done    with handshake negotiation.
> - The client responds with a Certificate message, which contains the    client's certificate.
> - The client sends a ClientKeyExchange message, which may contain a    PreMasterSecret, public key, or nothing. (Again, this depends on the
>     selected cipher.) This PreMasterSecret is encrypted using the public
>     key of the server certificate.
> - The client sends a CertificateVerify message, which is a signature    over the previous handshake messages using the client's certificate's 
>     private key. This signature can be verified by using the client's
>     certificate's public key. This lets the server know that the client
>     has access to the private key of the certificate and thus owns the
>     certificate. The client and server then use the random numbers and
>     PreMasterSecret to compute a common secret, called the "master
>     secret". All other key data for this connection is derived from this
>     master secret (and the client- and server-generated random values),
>     which is passed through a carefully designed pseudorandom function.
> - The client now sends a ChangeCipherSpec record, essentially telling    the server, "Everything I tell you from now on will be authenticated
>     (and encrypted if encryption was negotiated). " The ChangeCipherSpec
>     is itself a record-level protocol and has type 20 and not 22.
>     Finally, the client sends an encrypted Finished message, containing a 
>     hash and MAC over the previous handshake messages.
> - The server will attempt to decrypt the client's Finished message and    verify the hash and MAC. If the decryption or verification
>     fails, the    handshake is considered to have failed and the
>     connection should be    torn down.
> - Finally, the server sends a ChangeCipherSpec, telling the client,    "Everything I tell you from now on will be authenticated (and
>     encrypted if encryption was negotiated). " The server sends its own
>     encrypted Finished message.
> - The client performs the same decryption and verification.
>
> Application phase:
>
> - At this point, the "handshake" is complete and the application    protocol is enabled, with content type of 23. Application messages
>     exchanged between client and server will also be encrypted exactly
>     like in their Finished message.

Comment: So the client's private key will not be prone to reverse engineering?

Comment: Obviously if you have access to the source or the device, it's prone to reverse engineering. But you've already lost if an attacker has physical access to your device (or your binaries for that matter).

Comment: The mobile application that I talked about should be publicly available, so I think this approach will still be prone to reverse engineering?

Comment: Yep that's right